# Dictionary is empty after insert tons of items into it - Multiprocess sharing global variables

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

I am scrapping a page source already downloaded, and I am using multiprocessing to get this faster. Each file is a page with N news/articles, after scrapped-off desired info, each news is save in a dictionary with id as key. In the end I would to convert this dictionary to json

```
def handler(self, file):
        articles = self.open_text_file(self.path+file)
        for n in articles:
            try:
                id = self.investing.extract_id(n)
                image_url = self.investing.extract_image(n)
                url, title = self.investing.extract_title(n)
                id = url.split('-')[-1]
                text = self.investing.extract_text(n)

                self.news[id] = { 'url' : self.base_url+url,
                                  'image' : image_url,
                                  'title' : title,
                                  'text' : text}
            except KeyError:
                pass

    def extract_info(self):
        task = self.create_tasks()
        with Pool(CPU_COUNT) as pool:
            pool.map(self.handler, task)

        with open('financial_news.json', 'a', encoding='utf8') as  file:
            json.dump(self.news, file, indent=4)
```

This return a empty json file, without any news. Have you guys any idea what I am doing wrong?

I would like to have a dict **something like this**

```
"2998451": {
    "url": 
    "image": 
    "title": 
    "text": 
},
"2998427": {
    "url": 
    "image": 
    "title": 
    "text": 
},
"2998412": {
    "url": 
    "image": 
    "title": 
    "text": 
}
```

Comment: Is the json file literally empty?  Or is it a dictionary with no contents, i.e. `{}`?

Comment: a dictionary with no content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiprocessing.  Each process gets its own copy of `self`.  Each process is modifying its own copy of `self.news`, and the `self.news` is your main process is never touched.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to have your threads put their partial results on a multiprocessing queue, and then your main thread can read the partial results off that queue and save them in the one and only `self.news` that matters.

---

Actually, I've changed my mind.

```
   def handler(self, file):
        news = {}
        ....
        ... same code but use news rather than self.news ...
        ...
        return news

    def extract_info(self):
        self.news = {}
        task = self.create_tasks()
        with Pool(CPU_COUNT) as pool:
            for news in pool.map(self.handler, task):
                self.news |= news
        ...
```

More or less the same code you've got, but the tasks don't try to set a global variable. They just return their result to the main task, when uses it to update the main instance of `self.news`.

If you're using Python older than 3.9, use `self.news.update(news)`.

It may also be more efficient to use `imap` or `imap_unordered`.  You don't care what order your results come back.  See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) for more details.

---

If you do decide you want to use queues:

```
    def handler(self, task, queue):
       ......
       for n in articles:
           ....
           queue.add([id, .... info ....])
       queue.add(None) # Marker indicating we're done

    def extract_info(self):
       manager = mp.Manager()
       queue = manager.Queue()
       count = len(task)

       with Pool(CPU_COUNT) as pool:
           pool.starmap(self.handler, [(t, queue) for t in task])
           while count > 0:
               item = queue.get()
               if item is None: 
                    count -= 1
               else:
                    id, value = item
                    news[id] = value
        ....
```

Comment: Or in this case, since it's all I/O bound anyway so threads would work just fine, might as well just change `from multiprocessing import Pool` to `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` to get a thread-based pool and a single shared object.

Comment: I get it. But honestly I do have any idea how to do this. Have you some example or documentation?

Comment: @ShadowRanger is right.  The simplest solution would be to replace Pool with ThreadPool.  No need to touch anything else.  This is assuming that your code is IO bound and that not a lot of work is done on each image.  If that's not the case, let me see if I can get some sample Queue code for you.

Comment: It is CPU bound, I use multithread to make the request and download page source, and multiprocessing to scrap the infos from pages. There are more than 10k pages downloaded

Comment: It works !! Thanks a lot

PS: to add item in queue I use put(), add() did not work

Comment: Sorry.  Bad copying on my part.